# C++ FindWindow() Issues

Tags: c++, findwindow

I am trying to make a function find a window handle. I have done this many times before the following way:

```
HWND windowHandle
windowHandle = FindWindow(NULL, "NameOfWindowIAmLookingFor");
```

However, I then tried to do the following:

```
string myString = "NameOfWindowIAmLookingFor";
HWND windowHandle
windowHandle = FindWindow(NULL, myString);
```

and the following error comes up:

```
error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>)' to 'LPCSTR {aka const char*} ' for argument '2' to 'HWND__* FindWindowA(LPCSTR, LPCSTR)';
```

I have another function that is giving myString a value, so I want to pass that value as a variable to the FindWindow() function, but this error is coming up and I dont understand what is happening.

Question:: Why am I getting this error and how can I go about putting a string variable into the FindWindow() function?

Comment: The error is right there staring you in the face.

Comment: Look again at what `FindWindow` requires and what you pass to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why am I getting this error and how can I go about putting a string variable into the FindWindow() function?

The compiler error message is pretty clear. The `FindWindow()` function expects a `const char*` as second parameter, which `std::string` isn't.
To get a (`const`) pointer to the raw char array data managed by a `std::string` instance use the `c_str()` method:

```
FindWindow(NULL, myString.c_str());
```

Comment: your awesome dude. Im kinda a newby so many thanks for your well written explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to pass an object of type `std::string` into a function requiring a `LPCSTR` (which is an alias for `const char*`), but `std::string` doesn't implicitly convert to `const char*` and therefore you get the error message.
To get the function to work, you'll need to pass a C-style string (`const char*`), which you do by passing `myString.c_str()` instead of `myString`.